# Is this unprofessional when "Wappalyzer" sees all my technology?

Tags: python, coding-style, code-quality, django

After I installed "Wappalyzer", extension wich display technology, wich site using. I checked many sites and in most of cool projects, like "Youtube", "Github","stackoverflow" etc, wappalyzer display only some js framework and comercial things.
But when I checked sites, wich I builded on Django, wappalyzer display all my technologes in backend and frontend.
Maybe question is to broad, but I just saw this pattern and thought I do something wrong and some common things lies on a surface.

Comment: Do you think it is unprofessional if people see which technologies you use?  Transparency about technology is an essential part of professionalism within the open source community (Django itself is licensed under the BSD-license).

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg i didn't mean it. I mean in most of great projects like "StackExchange" Wappalyzer didn't saw any backend technologies, it saw only some Jquery and comercial staff. And decided, maybe I do something wrong

Comment: have you tried using Wappalyser on sites that use Django?  The Django website lists a few big names at the bottom of https://www.djangoproject.com/start/overview/.  Perhaps Django calls its back-end services using a specific pattern that Wappalyzer recognises.

Comment: here most popular sites, build by Django http://codecondo.com/popular-websites-django/ and no one display django on Wappalyzer except this http://yipit.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wappalyser will not be able to see the backend code running on a remote server. If you are running your Django site locally, then it will be able to inspect and report on everything.

or to put it another way, you do not have access to Youtube's backend server so you cannot tell anything about it or the technology it uses. You do have full access to your own, local server so you can tell everything about it.

Comment: I saw it not in local enviroment. And some site what I saw, displayed backend framework like RoR

Comment: @Baterson you'll have to ask wappalyser for support then, I don't know exactly what it does or how it does it. Possibly the other sites have a robots.txt or other restriction on apps making requests to view the servers, if not simply behind CDNs or proxies that report nothing.

Comment: Not familiar with Django or Wappalyzer but I would assume it looks for a "signature" in the served HTML to identify the back-end tech .. e.g. if a site has an `input` node with type="hidden" and name="__VIEWSTATE", then it's surely running ASP.NET WebForms on the server side.